# How can i remove particular string after the specified string using regex in php?

Tags: php, regex, string

i have a string like below,

```
 [Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM)#1 only: 1pmADV] => 2
    [Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM)#1 only: 2pmADV] => 1
    [Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM)#1 only: 2pmADV] => 1
    [Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM)#1 only: 1pmN/S+] => 1
    [Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM)#1 only: 2pmN/S+] => 1
    [Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM)#1 only: 3:30pmN/S+] => 1
```

i need remove the text after the string "pm" upto first occurance of "]".

for example,

```
from
[Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM)#1 only: 1pmADV] => 2
to
[Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM)#1 only: 1pm] => 2
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "[Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM)#1 only: 1pmADV] => 2"
echo preg_replace('/(?<=pm)\S*?(?=])/is', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

If all your strings are in this kind of format, you could use basic string functions

```
$str = "[Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM)#1 only: 1pmADV]";
$str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, "pm") + 2);
$str .= "]";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = preg_replace("/(pm)[^\]]+(\])/", "$1$2", $str);
```

This will remove all characters that are not `]` between `pm` and the first occurrence of `]`